# parse error in log in php

Tags: php, html

I am building a site which has a user database where the users can log in and sign up. When I test the PHP code for login, it says “parse error” once and `invalid { in line 16`. What is worng in my code?

```
<?php

$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxxxx") or die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
$test = mysql_select_db("users",$con)or die("unable to connect");

$result = "SELECT  * FROM users where username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$alpha = @mysql_query($result,$con);

if($alpha==1)
{
     $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
     setcookie("id",$row['id'],$expire);
     echo "Logged in. as <b>".$row['username']."</b>";
     $userID = $row['id'];
     header("index map.html")
 }
 else
 {
     echo "<b>Username or password  is wrong</b><br><br>";
     header("index.html")
 }

 mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated use MYSQLi

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your PHP here.

1. `header` needs a semi-colon closing it
2. `header` needs a **location** set.. i.e `header('location: index.html');`

you should replace

```
header("index map.html")
```

with

```
header("location: map.html");
```

Also you need to replace

```
header("index.html")
```

with

```
header("Location: index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

What the hell ? Where is row comes from ? **you didnt call any mysql_fecth_array or some thing related to traverse the result int a row** .. at least u code have used

> $row = mysql_fetch_result/array($result,$conn);

then use row as my suggestion ...

```
if($alpha==1)
{
     $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
     setcookie("id",$row['id'],$expire);
     echo "Logged in. as <b>".$row['username']."</b>";
     $userID = $row['id'];
     header("index map.html")
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all your code is very unsecure ! We can easily do some SQL Injection.
Try to use at least: `mysql_real_escape`. ([How to use mysql_real_escape_string function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691474/how-to-use-mysql-real-escape-string-function-in-php)). Also using PDO will be better (in my point of view).

The you forgot the dots in

`$result = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='.$user.' AND password='.$pass.'";` (line 7)

And you forgot to put the semi-colons and the field keyname (line 21) should be
`header("location: index.html");`

Best regards.

Answer (score -2):

your header() function is calling incorrectly correct it with

```
header("location:index-map.html");
```

Comment: what is `header('index` supposed to do?

Comment: there's no header called index.